# EF migration error while publishing .NET Core 3.1 app

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to publish my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API on Azure, but I am getting errors on EF migrations:

[image: EF Error Screenshot]

When I run the below command in console:

```
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --version 3.1.32
```

I get this error :

> Error NU1202: Package dotnet-ef 3.1.32 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / any. Package dotnet-ef 3.1.32 supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / any
>
> dotnet : The tool package could not be restored.

If I run `dotnet --info` , I get these results :

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   6.0.115
Commit:    1d8c2d93c0

Runtime Environment:

OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.19045
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64

Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.115\`

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.115 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Even though my application is in .NET Core 3.1, why is it looking for .NET 6? Where is it taking that value from and how can I get it working for my application?

I tried setting environment variable 'MSBuildSDKsPath' to point to SDK of 3.1.426, but still not luck

Comment: `publish my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API on Azure` --> the Azure WEB app running SDK you chose is .net 6?

Comment: Which manifest or which folder you have select when you run this command? Normally, each repro will contain a manifest.

Comment: I was able to get it working. I followed the below steps :
1) Created a global.json file in my solution as below : 
`{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.426"
  }
}`
2) Navigated to my solution in powershell and ran the below command:
`dotnet tool install  dotnet-ef --version 3.*`

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Visual studio 2022 with the .net Framework 3.1.

And able to install the `dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --version 3.1.32`

Using the below command

```
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 3.1.32
```

From the Command
Installed the Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 3.1.32.

[image]

Successfully Installed.

[image]

Used **Framework 3.1**, the same you mentioned.

[image]

Comment: I was able to install it finally using powershell, package manager console didn't work for me.