# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : publish failed (dotnet tool install dotnet-ef)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. It shows Entity Framework migration failed with the following error:

[image: dotnet tool install dotnet-ef]

I tried to uninstall `dotnet-ef` and install it back. I still get the same tool version:

```
dotnet uninstall dotnet-ef
dotnet tool update dotnet-ef --version 6.0.8 --global
```

My project is using ASP.NET Core version 6.0.8

Comment: Where do you  publish  ?  on Azure ? Have you check  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75819058/ef-migration-error-while-publishing-net-core-3-1-app ?

Comment: @QingGuo I am publishing to the local folder, Yes I tried already that link, still the same